# React Bootstrap Table in Card

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm facing a problem where I want to render a `Table` inside my `Card` component, but I want the final row of the `Table` to tail off with the `Card`, if that makes sense. Here's an example of the what I'm rendering at the moment:

[image]

As you can see, there is a bit extra below the `Away` row. Here's my React code:

```
const Market = ({ marketName, selections }) => {
  return (
    <div className="market-wrapper">
      <Card>
        <Card.Header className="market-header">{marketName}</Card.Header>
          <Table size="sm" striped bordered hover>
            <tbody>
              {selections.map((selection) => (
                <tr key={selection.id}>
                  <td style={{ width: "50%" }}>{selection.name}</td>
                  <td style={{ width: "50%" }}>{selection.price.toFixed(2)}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now here's the CSS:

```
.market-header {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #44494f;
    padding: 2.5px 15px;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #c8ceae;
  }
  
  .market-wrapper {
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px
  }
```

Can someone help me trim the bottom off the `Table` in the `Card`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Table` component in react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/table/#tables) uses [Bootstrap's styles for tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/), which feature `margin-bottom: 1rem` on the `table` element. You can override this by adding a style tag to the `<Table>` React component like this:

```
<Table size="sm" striped bordered hover style={{marginBottom: 0}}>
```

Alternatively, you could create a new CSS class and add it to the `<Table>` component:

```css
.market-table {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```
<Table className="market-table" size="sm" striped bordered hover>
```

In either case, your table will now have the extra bottom margin removed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a default `margin-bottom` in `Table` component which you can remove it by adding a `className` to `Table` component and set `margin-bottom` to `0`:

```
.market-table {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

[image: Edit zen-visvesvaraya-7i4v0]